# Minio permission denied

Tags: docker, permissions, minio

When I start my docker container, I have a problem with minio this is my error:

19:32:16.16 INFO  ==> ** Starting MinIO setup **

/opt/bitnami/scripts/libminio.sh: line 324: /data/.root_user: Permission denied

On windows it works but on linux not

this is my docker-compose settings:

```
        container_name: minio
        image: "bitnami/minio:latest"
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
            - "9001:9001"
        environment:
            - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=${ACCESS_KEY}
            - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
            - MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS=${BUCKET}
        volumes:
            - ./docker-volumes/s3-data:/data
        networks:
            - proxy
```

Comment: On what Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: My distribution is ZorinOS

Comment: It looks like your compose file is missing  command: server /data --console-address ":9001"

Answer (score 7):

### The problem

You are bind-mounting the directory `./docker-volumes/s3-data` into the container. Initially this directory doesn't exist, so Docker creates it -- as root. This means that the `/data` directory inside the container is owned by root.

Unfortunately, inside the container `minio` is running as user `1001`, so it doesn't have sufficient permissions to create files (or directories) inside `/data`.

### Solution 1: Docker volumes

If instead of bind-mounting a host directory you use a named docker volume, like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  minio:
    container_name: minio
    image: "bitnami/minio:latest"
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
        - "9001:9001"
    environment:
        - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=${ACCESS_KEY}
        - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
        - MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS=${BUCKET}
    volumes:
        - minio_data:/data

volumes:
  minio_data:
```

Then Docker will set the owner and permissions of the volume to the permissions of the directory on which you are mounting the volume. In the `bitnami/minio` image, `/data` looks like:

```
[lars@docker work]$ docker run -it --rm  bitnami/minio:latest ls -ld /data
[...]
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root root 6 May 22 00:55 /data
```

That is, it's writable by user `root` and group `root`. The minio container is running as UID 1001 and group `root`, so it's able to write to that directory.

### Solution 2: Futzing with permissions

You can, of course, explicitly pre-create the `docker-volumes/s3-data`
directory and then chown it to the appropriate userid:

```
sudo chown 1001 docker-volumes/s3-data
```

But in general, unless there's a reason why you need to use a specific
host directory, using a named Docker volume as in solution 1 is going
to be more manageable (because you don't need to know the container
userid in advance, and because you won't end up with files owned by
non-you userids in your home directory ).

Comment: I tried your 2 solutions but unfortunately none of them work I always have the same error even after.
I create folder docker-volumes/s3-data and give access but it doesn't change anything.Same for the docker compose modification

Comment: It would be great if you could provide more details other than "none of them work". Let's start with the first one: using exactly the `docker-comopse.yaml` I've provided here, ensure that we're starting from scratch by first running `docker-compose down -v`, then bring it up using `docker-compose up`.  Do you see the same permissions error?

Comment: Okay so I using exactly the docker-compose.yaml and when I using docker-compose up I have this error:
'services.volumes Additional property minio_data is not allowed'

When I use this command  'docker run -it --rm  bitnami/minio:latest ls -ld /data' I have this:drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 May 22 00:55 /data

Comment: That error sounds like you introduced some whitespace issues when copy/pasting. That would only happen if the `volumes` keyword was indented at the same level as the `minio` service. It should align with `services`. Please test the file exactly as presented.

Comment: Yess I really test the file exactly as presented but I have the same error so I tried the second solution so the command line passes but I still get the same type of error

Comment: @Anthony I ran into the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No. Changing owner of data directory does not help.

Comment: solution 2 has work for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a minikube, since I just needed it for testing purposes I added `--set persistence.enabled="false"`

The Full Command being:

```bash
helm install minio bitnami/minio --namespace minio --create-namespace --set image.debug="true" --set service.type="ClusterIP" --set persistence.enabled="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R 1001:1001 docker-volumes/s3-data
```